# Searching subtitle data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-model

Having the following data (simple srt)

```
1
00:02:17,440 --> 00:02:20,375
Senator, we're making our final

2
00:02:20,476 --> 00:02:22,501
approach into Coruscant.

...
```

what would be the best way to index it in Elasticsearch? Now here's the catch: I want search results highlights to link to the exact time the timestamp indicates. Also, there are phrases overlapping multiple srt rows (such as `final approach` in the example above).

My ideas are

- Index the srt file as list type, timestamps being the indexes. I'm believe this would not match phrases overlapping multiple keys
- Create custom tokenizer that only indexes the text part. I'm not sure how well can elasticsearch highlight the original content then.
- Index only the text part and map it back to timestamp outside of elasticsearch

Or is there yet another option that would solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: Maybe using a library to parse the subtitle for you, maybe you can find only which parses other formats too.

Comment: Is there an answer to the question now?

Answer (score 9):

Interesting question. Here's my take on it.

In essence, the subtitles "don't know" about each other — meaning that it'd be best to contain the previous and subsequent subtitle text in each doc (`n - 1`, `n`, `n + 1`) whenever applicable.

As such, you'd be gunning for a doc structure similar to:

```json
{
  "sub_id" : 0,
  "start" : "00:02:17,440",
  "end" : "00:02:20,375",
  "text" : "Senator, we're making our final",
  "overlapping_text" : "Senator, we're making our final approach into Coruscant."
}
```

To arrive at such a doc structure I used the following (inspired by [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23620587/8160318)):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple


def parse_subs(fpath):
    # "chunk" our input file, delimited by blank lines
    with open(fpath) as f:
        res = [list(g) for b, g in groupby(f, lambda x: bool(x.strip())) if b]

    Subtitle = namedtuple('Subtitle', 'sub_id start end text')

    subs = []

    # grouping
    for sub in res:
        if len(sub) >= 3:  # not strictly necessary, but better safe than sorry
            sub = [x.strip() for x in sub]
            sub_id, start_end, *content = sub  # py3 syntax
            start, end = start_end.split(' --> ')

            # ints only
            sub_id = int(sub_id)

            # join multi-line text
            text = ', '.join(content)

            subs.append(Subtitle(
                sub_id,
                start,
                end,
                text
            ))

    es_ready_subs = []

    for index, sub_object in enumerate(subs):
        prev_sub_text = ''
        next_sub_text = ''

        if index > 0:
            prev_sub_text = subs[index - 1].text + ' '

        if index < len(subs) - 1:
            next_sub_text = ' ' + subs[index + 1].text

        es_ready_subs.append(dict(
            **sub_object._asdict(),
            overlapping_text=prev_sub_text + sub_object.text + next_sub_text
        ))

    return es_ready_subs
```

Once the subtitles are parsed, they can be ingested into ES. Before that's done, set up the following mapping so that your timestamps are properly searchable and sortable:

```json
PUT my_subtitles_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "as_timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "HH:mm:ss,SSS"
          }
        }
      },
      "end": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "as_timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "HH:mm:ss,SSS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once that's done, proceed to ingest:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

from utils.parse import parse_subs

es = Elasticsearch()

es_ready_subs = parse_subs('subs.txt')

actions = [
    {
        "_index": "my_subtitles_index",
        "_id": sub_group['sub_id'],
        "_source": sub_group
    } for sub_group in es_ready_subs
]

bulk(es, actions)
```

Once ingested, you can target the original subtitle `text` and boost it if it directly matches your phrase. Otherwise, add a fallback on the `overlapping` text which'll ensure that both "overlapping" subtitles are returned.

Before returning, you can make sure that the hits are ordered by the `start`, ascending. That kind of defeats the purpose of boosting but if you do sort, you can specify `track_scores:true` in the URI to make sure the originally calculated scores are returned too.

Putting it all together:

```json
POST my_subtitles_index/_search?track_scores&filter_path=hits.hits
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": {
              "query": "final approach",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "overlapping_text": {
              "query": "final approach"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "start.as_timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

yields:

```json
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_subtitles_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : 6.0236287,
        "_source" : {
          "sub_id" : 0,
          "start" : "00:02:17,440",
          "end" : "00:02:20,375",
          "text" : "Senator, we're making our final",
          "overlapping_text" : "Senator, we're making our final approach into Coruscant."
        },
        "sort" : [
          137440
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_subtitles_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 5.502407,
        "_source" : {
          "sub_id" : 1,
          "start" : "00:02:20,476",
          "end" : "00:02:22,501",
          "text" : "approach into Coruscant.",
          "overlapping_text" : "Senator, we're making our final approach into Coruscant. Very good, Lieutenant."
        },
        "sort" : [
          140476
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and took a different approach.

1. Concatenate the caption lines to a whole piece of transcript.
2. Index the transcript into Elasticsearch , instead of caption lines.
3. Ask Elasticsearch to return highlight snippets.
4. Search snippets in transcript again on the client side to determine its proper position.
5. Map the snippets' start position into proper caption line, and get its corresponding timestamp information.

It's a lot easier for me to just shift this logic to the client side.

Comment: well the number 4 only work if you do not have dupplicated sentences

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you need to handle the proximity operator like ~10 then it would be a bad idea to split your transcript in different document.

One solution could be to hide information into your transcript like the time thanks to tag like <timeis=5000>

And then to ignore the time during tokenisation thanks to this.

"char_filter": {"my_char_filter": {"type" : "pattern_replace","pattern" : "<timeis=.*?'>","replacement" : ""}}

then highlight will not be broken.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!